# How to Show the same modal with different content onClick different buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load different content of Modals onClick of different button.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without seeing your code, please provide some more details

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the model content in state
2. In onClick pass the new content to the function and do setState
3. Change the visibility according to the logic

> Below is the code to send the argument to React member functions

```
onClick = {(e) => this.showModel(e , newContent) }
```

Can elaborate more if you share your code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 {["first","second"].map(option => {
                return (
                  <Button
                    size="small"
                    color="secondary"
                    variant="raised"
                    onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
                  >
                    {option}
                  </Button>
                );
              })}


       <Dialog
            open={this.state.open}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
          >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
              {"Use Google's location service?"}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                hello /here must be different names/
              </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
          </Dialog>
```